# Importing CSV file into a psql table

Tags: sql, psql

I have a csv file with 2 columns, one column is an id and the other one a name. No csv header.

```
"5138334","Here's Where the Story Ends"
"36615796","W31CZ-D"
"10283436","Elliant"
"8773661","Dobos torte"
"33139146","RTP Informação"
"2846867","The Legend of the Rollerblade Seven"
"36001757","Prescription Monitoring Program"
"2574520","Greg Wells"
"4498288","Catonsville Community College"
"15429275","Nozières"
"31736463","Bályok"
```

how do I insert this into a psql table?

I have tried creating a table.

```
create table csvtable(id bigserial not null primary key, 
                      csv_id int not null, 
                      csv_title varchar(100) not null);
```

and other variations without the id column(I tried making my own id in case the existing id wasn't unique)

and I have tried inserting the data through the copy command.

```
copy csvtable from 'file.csv' with csv;
```

and other variations with delimeter, etc. but no luck.

Comment: Did you try with (FORMAT csv)?

Comment: If you are using oracle DB then you can user oracle sql loader..

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm

Comment: @likwidfire2k  yeah I get this error ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "id"
CONTEXT:  COPY csvtable, line 1, column id: "id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify which columns you are copying:

```
\copy csvtable(csv_id, csv_title) FROM 'data.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv)
```

Note that this is using `\copy` from psql rather than `COPY` (which might not be needed if the file is on the same server).

Comment: what if the file doesn't have labeled columns? how do I refer to them?

Comment: The columns above are referring to the table, not the file, i.e. you're assigning the first column of the file to `csv_id` and the second to `csv_title`. You cannot cherry pick columns from the CSV. You need to import all of them. If that is not compatible with the table, either change your CSV file or import it into a temporary table to accommodate the extra columns and then copy over the desired data from this temporary table to your final table.